# using ServiceStack.Text: override the CreateInstance stuff?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack.Text's JSON serialization stuff for one of my projects. However, when deserializing data I would like the ability to override the part that creates the instance of the object. I would like it to use my IoC container to create the instance of any new objects needed during deserialization. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [ServiceStack's JSON Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) there are hooks on:

```
JsConfig<T>.OnSerializingFn
```

and

```
JsConfig<T>.OnDeserializedFn
```

That should let you do this.

Comment: I saw those methods, but I still want the standard parsing functionality that sets property values. If I use those, I end up creating a new object and then copying over properties. However, I also end up manually determining which properties were in the JSON so that I don't overwrite properties that weren't in the incoming data.

Comment: There is no such functionality in ServiceStack.Text

Comment: As an alternate approach could we add the ability to deserialize into an existing instance?

Comment: That doesn't exist either. You can use `TranslateTo<T>` or `PopulateFrom<T>` to map between models, otherwise feel free to fork and contribute support and send a pull-req for it :)